# How to exit a process run with Ruby if it takes more than 5 seconds?

Tags: ruby, process, execution-time

I'm implementing a checking system in Ruby. It runs executables with different tests. If the solution is not correct, it can take forever for it to finish with certain hard tests. That's why I want to limit the execution time to 5 seconds.

I'm using system() function to run executables:

```
system("./solution");
```

.NET has a great `WaitForExit()` method, what about Ruby?.

Is there a way to limit external process' execution time to 5 seconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the standard timeout library, like so:

```
require 'timeout'
Timeout::timeout(5) { system("./solution") }
```

This way you wont have to worry about synchronization errors.

Comment: I chose this as accepted answer, because unlike EnabrenTane's solution, each test doesn't take 5 seconds minimum to complete. I use system("sudo killall solution") to kill the running process.

Answer (score 4):

Fork your child which executes "./solution", sleep, check if its done, if not kill it. This should get you started.

```
pid = Process.fork{ system("./solution")}
sleep(5)
Process.kill("HUP", pid)
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M003153

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see I can use the fork method. But how can I connect it with system("./solution")?

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I need. There's just one problem. Now all tests take 5 seconds. However most of the tests are passed in less than a second. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: It turned out that the processes were killed only "inside" Ruby. It went on to the next tests. However they were still in activity monitor eating all the CPU.